# Prove that $\tan (x)=\sin (x)+1$ has only one solution in $\left(−\frac π2,\frac π2\right)$

Tags: calculus

> Prove that $\tan (x)= \sin (x) +1$ has only one solution in $\left(−\frac π2,\fracπ2\right)$
>   and we *must* use *Rolle's rule* and *Cauchy's mean value theorem*.

I know how to solve it without the use of
Rolle's rule and Cauchy's mean value theorem.
Can you help?

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\tan(x)-\sin(x)-1$.
You have $f'(x)=\sec^2(x)-\cos(x)$.
Since $\sec^2(x)-\cos(x)$ has the same sign as $x$ for $x\in[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, we know that $f'(x)\geq0$ in this interval and $f'(x)>0$ for $x\in[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]\setminus\{0\}$.
Therefore $f$ is strictly increasing and can have at most one zero.

Using *Rolle's Theorem*, it does not satisfy the hypothesis that $f$ is differnetiable for all vales of $x$ in the open interval $(a,b)$, $f$ is continuous at $x=a$ or $x=b$, and that $f(a)=f(b)=0$; however the conclusion can be true even though the hypothesis is false for $f$ stating that there exists one number $x=c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$.

Using the *Mean Value Theorem*, it does not satisfy the hypothesis $f$ is differnetiable for all vales of $x$ in the open interval $(a,b)$, $f$ is continuous at $x=a$ or $x=b$; however satisfies the conclusion that there exists at least one number $x=c$ in $(a,b)$ such that 
$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$

The main thing to remember is that **the hypothesis might be wrong but the conclusion may as well end up true**.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $f(x) = \tan x - \sin x - 1$ has $f'(x) = \sec^2 x - \cos x=\dfrac{1-\cos^3 x}{\cos^2 x} \geq 0$, and $f(-\pi/4) = -2 +\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < 0$, and since $\lim_{ x \to \pi/2^{-}} f(x) = + \infty$, we have for $M = 1$, you can find a delta $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x- \pi/2| < \delta \Rightarrow f(x) > M = 1$. Thus by continuity of $f$ and by using MVT on $(-\pi/4, \pi/2-\epsilon)$, there is a root and coupled with $f'(x) > 0$, there is only one root, with $\epsilon$ can be selected easily from $\delta$.